# Remove (or hide) default Permissions from Django

Tags: python, django

I'm developing a Django app that will have two administration backends. One for daily use by "normal" users and the default one for more advanced tasks and for the developers.

The application uses some custom permissions but none of the default ones. So I'm currently looking for a way to remove the default permissions, or at least a way to hide them from the "daily" admin backend without large modifications.

Comment: I've never tried it so I'm hesitant to put it down as an answer, but you can probably remove the database entries for them. If your admin users are all classified as superusers, they are assumed to have all permissions anyway (I think), and thus you shouldn't need the records. No promises, though.

Comment: yes if they are superusers every call to a "has permission" method will return true. But I don't think that is the idea since you are using custom permissions. Do you prevent the Django admin from checking the default permissions? Because if a user doesn't have any default permissions for a certain object, it won't show up in the admin.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A new feature introduced in Django 1.7 is the ability to define the default permissions. As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#default-permissions) if you set this to empty none of the default permissions will be created.

A working example would be:

```python
class Blar1(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique = True, blank = False, null = False, verbose_name= "Name")

    class Meta:
        default_permissions = ()
```

Comment: But you can't use this method to avoid Django create permissions for its own models like Session, nor it works for third party models.

Comment: Of cause not, and you should not be playing with them anyway. What reason would you need this?

Comment: I don't think "you should not be playing with them" is correct, if you're not using django admin you don't need those permissions. Removing them manually doesn't affect anything here.

Comment: "What reason would you need this?" I wanna use my totally customized permission system on top of django permissions. When I'm showing a list of all permissions to admin user for example so that he can assign permissions to users I should manually filter out django's internal permissions. It's just annoying.

Comment: Note: default permissions have to be removed at the very start, ie while creating the model.

Answer (score 21):

**UPDATE: Django 1.7 supports the customization of [default permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/options/#default-permissions)**

**Original Answer**

*The following is valid for Django **prior to version 1.7***

This is standard functionality of the [*auth*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) contrib application.

It handles the *post_syncdb* signal and creates the permissions (the standard 3: *add*, *change*, *delete*, plus any custom ones) for each model; they are stored in the *auth_permission* table in the database.

So, **they will be created each time you run the syncdb management command**

You have some choices. None is really elegant, but you can consider:

1. Dropping the *auth* contrib app and provide your own [*authentication backend*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#authentication-backends).

   **Consequences** -> you will lose the admin and other custom apps built on top of the auth User model, but if your application is highly customized that could be an option for you
2. Overriding the behaviour of the *post_syncdb* signal inside the auth app (inside [\django\contrib\auth\management__init__.py](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py) file)

   **Consequences** -> be aware that without the basic permissions the Django admin interface won't be able to work (and maybe other things as well).
3. Deleting the basic permissions (*add*, *change*, *delete*) for each model inside the *auth_permission* table (manually, with a script, or whatever).

   **Consequences** -> you will lose the admin again, and you will need to delete them each time you run *syncdb*.
4. Building your own *Permission application/system* (with your own decorators, middlewares, etc..) or extending the existing one.

   **Consequences** -> none, if you build it well - this is one of the cleanest solutions in my opinion.

*A final consideration*: changing the contrib applications or Django framework itself is never considered a good thing: you could break something and you will have hard times if you will need to upgrade to a newer version of Django.

So, if you want to be as clean as possibile, consider rolling your own permission system, or extending the standard one ([django-guardian](https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian) is a good example of an extension to django permissions). It won't take much effort, and you can build it the way it feels right for you, overcoming the limitations of the standard django permission system. And if you do a good work, you could also consider to open source it to enable other people using/improving your solution =)

Comment: Well, then I have to life with them.

Comment: But you can't use the updated method to avoid Django create permissions for its own models like Session, nor it works for third party models.

Answer (score 19):

I struggled with this same problem for a while and I think I've come up with a clean solution. Here's how you hide the permissions for Django's auth app:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

class MyGroupAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyGroup

    permissions = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        Permission.objects.exclude(content_type__app_label='auth'), 
        widget=admin.widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple(_('permissions'), False))


class MyGroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyGroupAdminForm
    search_fields = ('name',)
    ordering = ('name',)

admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.register(MyGroup, MyGroupAdmin)
```

Of course it can easily be modified to hide whatever permissions you want. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: What do you mean with the model called "MyGroup"?

Answer (score 7):

ShadowCloud gave a good rundown. Here's a simple way to accomplish your goal.

Add these line in your admin.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
admin.site.register(Permission)
```

You can now add/change/delete permissions in the admin. Remove the unused ones and when you have what you want, go back and remove these two lines from admin.py.

As was mentioned by others, a subsequent syncdb will put everything back.

Comment: Perfect! This is much simpler than trekking through the database!

Answer (score 4):

Built on top of the solution by @pmdarrow, I've come up with a relatively clean solution to patch the Django admin views.

See: https://gist.github.com/vdboor/6280390

It extends the `User` and `Group` admin to hide certain permissions.

Answer (score 2):

You can't easily delete those permissions (so that syncdb won't put them back), but you can hide them from the admin interface. The idea is, as described by others, to override the admin forms but you have to do this for both users and groups.
Here is the admin.py with the solution:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import GroupAdmin, UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm

#
# In the models listed below standard permissions "add_model", "change_model"
# and "delete_model" will be created by syncdb, but hidden from admin interface.
# This is convenient in case you use your own set of permissions so the list
# in the admin interface wont be confusing.
# Feel free to add your models here. The first element is the app name (this is
# the directory your app is in) and the second element is the name of your model
# from models.py module of your app (Note: both names must be lowercased).
#
MODELS_TO_HIDE_STD_PERMISSIONS = (
    ("myapp", "mymodel"),
)

def _get_corrected_permissions():
    perms = Permission.objects.all()
    for app_name, model_name in MODELS_TO_HIDE_STD_PERMISSIONS:
        perms = perms.exclude(content_type__app_label=app_name, codename='add_%s' % model_name)
        perms = perms.exclude(content_type__app_label=app_name, codename='change_%s' % model_name)
        perms = perms.exclude(content_type__app_label=app_name, codename='delete_%s' % model_name)
    return perms

class MyGroupAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Group

    permissions = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        _get_corrected_permissions(),
        widget=admin.widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple(('permissions'), False),
        help_text = 'Hold down "Control", or "Command" on a Mac, to select more than one.'
    )

class MyGroupAdmin(GroupAdmin):

    form = MyGroupAdminForm

class MyUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    user_permissions = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        _get_corrected_permissions(),
        widget=admin.widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple(('user_permissions'), False),
        help_text = 'Hold down "Control", or "Command" on a Mac, to select more than one.'
    )

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    form = MyUserChangeForm

admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.register(Group, MyGroupAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating your own user management backend and only want to show your custom permissions you can filter out the default permissions by excluding permission with a name that starts with "Can".

WARNING:
You must remember not to name your permissions starting with "Can"!!!!
If they decide to change the naming convention this might not work.

With credit to pmdarrow this is how I did this in my project:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.contrib import admin    

class UserEditForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User

        exclude = (
                   'last_login',
                   'is_superuser',
                   'is_staff',
                   'date_joined',
                   )

    user_permissions = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        Permission.objects.exclude(name__startswith='Can'), 
        widget=admin.widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple(_('permissions'), False))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent Django from creating permissions, you can block the signals from being sent.

If you put this into a management/**init**.py in any app, it will bind to the signal handler before the auth framework has a chance (taking advantage of the dispatch_uid debouncing).

```
from django.db.models import signals

def do_nothing(*args, **kwargs):
  pass

signals.post_syncdb.connect(do_nothing, dispatch_uid="django.contrib.auth.management.create_permissions")
signals.post_syncdb.connect(do_nothing, dispatch_uid="django.contrib.auth.management.create_superuser")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming here somewhat frustrated, since what I believe to be the "correct" answer is mentioned here:

> UPDATE: Django 1.7 supports the customization of default permissions

But I cannot find any *examples* of carrying this out. In my case I wanted to remove "add" permission from a few models (but not all), because for those models the add permission is implied by other things. This is how it looks in the model definition:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        default_permissions = ('change', 'delete', 'view')
```

You need to cover 2 things in the migration. The first thing is the change to the `Meta`, which will be covered by a simple `makemigrations` command. This gets added to the `operations` and looks loosely like this:

```
migrations.AlterModelOptions(
    name='mymodel',
    options={
        'default_permissions': ('change', 'delete', 'view'),
    },
),
```

Now you need a data migration to delete the entry from the permissions table, assuming that this is an existing model. New models will not need either of these migration steps, so that's nice. So add this to `operations`

```
migrations.RunPython(delete_add_permission),
```

with the corresponding method defined separately.

```
def delete_add_permission(apps, schema_editor):
    Permission = apps.get_model('auth', 'Permission')

    perm = Permission.objects.filter(name='add_mymodel').first()
    if perm:
        perm.delete()
```