# How to only sync custom permissions with syncdb?

Tags: django, django-models

Is it possible to have the manage.py syncdb command ONLY sync custom permissions to the `auth_permission` table? I don't want the default three permissions installed for the app models, i.e. `foo.add_bar`, `foo.change_bar`, `foo.delete_bar`. I specify my custom permissions in my model classes like the django documentation suggests:

```
class Meta:
    permissions = (
        ("admin", "Can create/edit/delete projects"),
        ("user", "Can view projects"),
    )
```

Thank you!

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062655/remove-or-hide-default-permissions-from-django

Answer (score 10):

You have 2 solutions here, AFAIK :

1. manually insert in the `auth_permission` table ;
2. Add in a command [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2398/).

Adding a command is pretty straightforward. Just create a module `sync_perms.py` (with the snippet code) in a `management.commands` package in one of your apps ([here the official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/)).

Then run :

```
python manage.py sync_perms
```

*Et voilà !*

Comment: `from django.db.models import get_models, get_app` seems been deprecated in django3.

Answer (score 1):

Just posted the solution to 
[Remove (or hide) default Permissions from Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062655/remove-or-hide-default-permissions-from-django?lq=1).
The idea is not to prevent them from being created by syncdb, but to hide them from the admin interface.

Answer (score 1):

first you must find the content type id for your application  the content type 
can be found with this query

```
select * from django_content_type;
```

then you execute the query to add to database the custom permission you want for example

```
insert into auth_permission(name,content_type_id,codename) values
('Can add name',12,'can_add_name');
```

in the above query ,   name is a string which the user see in permissions list , the number is the application id found from the first query  and codename is the  code that you will use in templates for example in template you can use

```
{{perms.application.can_add_name}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `default_permissions` on Meta to be empty tuple. (default value is `('add', 'change', 'delete')`). [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#default-permissions).

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # properties definition...
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("admin", "Can create/edit/delete projects"),
            ("user", "Can view projects"),
        )
        default_permissions = ()
```

I also like to have special `MyAppProperties` model with `Meta.managed=False` to hold my app-wide permissions.

```
class MyAppPermissions(models.Model):
    # properties definition...
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        permissions = (
            ("admin", "Can create/edit/delete projects"),
            ("user", "Can view projects"),
        )
        default_permissions = ()
```

this way it won't create a database table, but permissions for it. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#managed).