# Django add custom permission in model

Tags: django, django-models, django-permissions

I have order model, and i want add custom permission using class META

```
class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('0', 'Готов'),
        ('1', 'Ждет оплаты'),
        ('2', 'Подтвержден'),
        ('3', 'В работе'),
        ('4', 'Выполнено'),
    )

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_created=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='1')
    payed = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    edited = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta(object):
        permissions = (
            ("can_change_status", "Can change status"),
        )
```

I haven't database. I made *syncdb*, but I don't see own permission not in *group*, not in *user*, not in table *auth_permission*. I've add that permission in *auth_permission* table, no effect.

Have any ideas or advice what I should do or read?

Comment: Have you tried with this answer?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7258464/4598504

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typo in `class META`, must be `class Meta`